# Bootstrap, navbar-collapse. How to change the background color of the whole navbar when the navbar-collapse is shown/open (on mobile screen)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I would like to ask how to change a bg color of the navbar when the navbar-collapse is shown. I need the different bg color when is the navbar-collapse shown and different bg color when is collapsed. Do someone know the solution by using CSS or JS ? 
I can't figure it out.
I will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Without any example code, I can't apply much, but I can provide you an example using JQuery. Lets say hypothetically `navbar-collapse` shows/hides by setting the `display` property as `block/none` you could listen for the style attribute to be applied.

```
if($('#navbar-collapse:visible').length == 0){
   $('#navbar').css('background: #000')
}
```

This would turn the navbar black if the `navbar-collapse` was visible.